# Click icon in jQuery UI accordion heading to open Bootstrap modal, but prevent accordion collapse event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have a jQuery UI accordion.  In each heading bar there is an 'Edit' icon.  Clicking this icon opens a Bootstrap modal.

At the moment, clicking the icon launches the modal but obviously triggers the accordion menu expand/collapse event as well.  How can I prevent it?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/M3MDJ/3/

As far as I can tell, the Bootstrap modal event happens first because if I use `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` nothing at all happens; even the modal is prevented from opening.

Comment: show the code you've tried and create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @charlietfl Added jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to control modal with javascript not auto inlitialize with `data-` attributes. Otherwise when bootstrap automatically binds the click handler it has no way to know not to propagate the event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#modal-edit').modal()
  })
  $('#accordion').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
        active: false
  });  
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/M3MDJ/4/